# Problem passing a datetime variable into a dynamic SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to execute a dynamic SQL query, but I'm getting an error Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '2020-09-15 18:'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2020-09-15 18:'

There must be something wrong with the datetime variable.
Can anybody suggest how this should be done properly ?

```
declare @paramDailyOutput nvarchar(100), @retrieveDailyVal real
declare @paramDaily float
declare @retrieveDailyID varchar(100) = 'table_53'

declare @startTime datetime, @currTime datetime = GETDATE()
set @startTime = DATEADD(hour, -1, @currTime)

             set @paramDailyOutput = 'SELECT @paramDaily = max(value) - min(value) FROM ' + @retrieveDailyID + ' where read_date between ''' + convert(nvarchar(200), @startTime, 120) + ''' and ''' + convert(nvarchar(200), @currTime, 120) + ''''
             exec sp_executesql @paramDailyOutput, N' @paramDaily float OUTPUT', @paramDaily = @paramDaily output
             select @paramDaily
```

Comment: To write dynamic sql you must be able to debug it when something goes wrong. So rather than rage-quit the development, just select the string you generated so you can see exactly what the code you wrote did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You strings are too short, you're going way over 100 characters.

Try changing everything to 250 or even 300 characters. Or better yet, NVARCHAR(1000).